# how to pass a foreach loop into an API payload - using CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a dynamically generated upload form , the name values are based on the API
i am expected to pass all these values back to another api

1. the link to uploaded file
2. Description
3. Serial key

these values to be posted are best retrieved via a for each loop

my question is how to pass the values from a foreach loop into a payload or if there is something i need to do as i am new into programming
[front end of dynamically generated form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO71a.png)

API CODE

```
public function post_Loan(){ 
     $ProductCode=$this->input->post('productcode');
     $loantype=$this->input->post('loantype');
     $Amount = $this->input->post('Amount');
     $Instalment= $this->input->post('Instalment');
     $bankaccno = $this->input->post('bankaccno');
     $bankname = $this->input->post('bankname');
     $loanpurpose = $this->input->post('loanpurpose');
     $repay =  $this->input->post('repay');
    
   // looped uploaded doc based on product code selected 
    if (!empty($_POST["productcode"])) {
       $Loandoucuments = $this->Gemini_model->get_loandocument($_POST["productcode"]);
       $config['upload_path'] ='./images/';
       $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
       $config['max_size'] = 2000;
       $config['max_width'] = 1500;
       $config['max_height'] = 1500;
     // $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
       $this->upload->initialize($config);
       foreach($Loandoucuments as $doc){
       if (!$this->upload->do_upload($doc['SerialKey'])) {
         } else {
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                //description , serial key and link to uploaded file 
              $doc['Description']; //Description 
               $doc['SerialKey']; // SerialKey
               anchor('images/'.$data['file_name']) ; //UploadLink
          }
      } 
    }else{ }

    
 
    $url = "http://demo.geminiapp.net/service/Request.svc/api/loanrequest";


     $data = [


        

 "Amount"=>$Amount,
 "BankAccountNo"=>$bankaccno,
 "BankCode"=>$bankname,
 "ContractType"=>$loantype, 
 "CurrencyCode"=>$currency,
 "CustomerID"=>"3",
 "Document"=>[
   "ContractDocs"=>[
   "Description"=> //$doc['Description'],
   "SerialKey"=>//$doc['SerialKey'],
   "UploadLink"=>//$Link to be uploaded '
   ]
 ],
 "Installment"=>$Instalment,
 "LNAccountNo"=>"00",//$AccountNo,
 "ProductCode"=>$ProductCode,
 "PurposeKey"=>$loanpurpose,
 "RepayKey"=>$repay

  

 
 ];


 
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
       'Authorization: Bearer yP5lnti7wDChJxwmBYz7dpbgbzGqQRG1dyvAZihesrA=',
       'Content-Type: application/json'
     ]);   
       $response = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     $result = json_decode($response);
     print_r($result);


 
 }//post loan
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assigning `$data` to an array, you can check if it (`$data`) was created earlier at `$data = $this->upload->data();` then you may assing it's data directly to the new array.

```php
$data = [
 "Amount"=>$Amount,
 "BankAccountNo"=>$bankaccno,
 "BankCode"=>$bankname,
 "ContractType"=>$loantype, 
 "CurrencyCode"=>$currency,
 "CustomerID"=>"3",
 "Document"=>[
   "ContractDocs"=>[
   "Description"=> isset($data['Description']) ? $data['Description'] : '',
   "SerialKey"=> isset($data['SerialKey']) ? $data['SerialKey'] : '',
   "UploadLink"=> isset($data['file_name']) ? anchor('images/'.$data['file_name']) : ''
   ]
 ],
 "Installment"=>$Instalment,
 "LNAccountNo"=>"00",//$AccountNo,
 "ProductCode"=>$ProductCode,
 "PurposeKey"=>$loanpurpose,
 "RepayKey"=>$repay
 ];
```

Where `"SerialKey"=> isset($data['SerialKey']) ? $data['SerialKey'] : ''` construction works like this:
If `$data['SerialKey']` is set, then assign it to `"SerialKey"`, if it not set, then assign `''` to `"SerialKey"`.

Comment: the challenge is that wit tis solution its taken only the last values from the results in the loop

Comment: Then, the solution is depends on how it should looks in your `another api`. Show expected result (array).

Comment: http://demo.geminiapp.net/service/Request.svc/api/help/operations/UpdateLoanRequest